# Eloquent Many to Many Where Sum Equal to a Column Value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have `Order` and `Invoice` models which have many-to-many relationships connected using the `OrderInvoice` pivot. The tables have attributes:

```
order
-----
id
total

invoice
-------
id
total

order_invoice
-------------
order_id
invoice_id
subtotal
```

I want to get every `Order` which sum of its invoices **subtotal** (from the pivot) is less than the `Order` total. This includes `Order` which have no invoice at all.
How can I achieve that using the eloquent query builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly then you can do the below.

```
$order=\App\Models\Order::query()->whereHas("invoice",function ($query){
        $query->havingRaw('orders.total>sum(order_invoice.subtotal)')->groupBy('order_id');
    })->orDoesntHave("invoice")
        ->get();
```

If you still have error then please post both order and invoice model code so we can see where it went wrong

Comment: Nice answer. It works. But the problem is I also want to include the order which have no invoice at all. How can I improve your code above? (I'll edit my question as well)

Answer (score 0):

// Model Name
Order Model

```
public function order_invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order_invoice')->withTimestamps();
    }


$total_invoice_count = Order::order_invoice()->count('order_id');
```